# Why is this illegal in java array passed into constructor to a method?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I want to create an object that lets me initialize as array

`arraysort test_array = new arraysort.(array_to_be_input);`

Then it will have several methods such as sort remove duplicates ect.. but I want the array too be sorted as soon as it is passed into the class.

I have just written the following code and I don't understand why it has gone wrong.

```
public class arraysort{
   int[] a;

/* array is input when the object is created */
    arraysort(int[] a){
        this.a=a;  
    }

/*array is put into the sort method*/
    public int[] sortit(a){
        int i = 0;

        while(i<array.length){  
            i++;
        }
    return a;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Comment: `main()` method is empty. Instantiate `arraysort` in `main()` method.
BTW class names should start with an uppercase character.

Comment: what is the exception you get? please describe your problem more exactly.

Comment: Ok, so what's the problem?

Comment: I said I'm working on the class it is not finished.

Comment: I said I'm working on the class it is not finished.

Comment: Sorry I hit enter by mistake the error message is for the sortit method it doesn't recognise a and says "cannot find symbol a"

Comment: You are not following Java's syntax, does the declaration of `sortit` look good to you?

Comment: It helps to use an IDE and follow Java's syntax and know the basics of programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

->You while condition has  a typo:-

Change this `while(i<array.length)` to this `while(i<a.length)`

-> You `main()` method is empty, call your code in main method to execute it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int[] arr=new int[3];
arr[0]=1;
arr[1]=4;
arr[2]=2;

arraysort as=new arraysort(arr);
as.sortit(arr);
}
```

Some other points to highlight are:-

-> Begin classnames with Capital case:- `class ArraySort`

->Your `sortit(a)` method takes input a , whereas it is not required since it is a class variable and can be accessed directly in the method.

-> Your `sortit(a)` method does not perform any sorting/computation on `a` and simply returns it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in your `sortit` method.

You forgot to declare your parameters and you try to access an array that is not existent (with array.length). Try it the following way:

```
public int[] sortit(int[] a){ // <--- declare your parameters
    int i = 0;

    while(i < a.length){  //<--- access passed parameters
        //whatever you want to do
    }


    return a;
}
```

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer as right if it helped you.